# Validate FQDN Name without negative lookahead

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, fqdn

I have found this link(www.regextester.com/103452) to validate the based on REGEX.

```
(?=^.{4,253}$)(^((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}$)
```

But there's one problem, Oracle doesn't recognize Positive/Negative Lookahead.

The first positive lookahead `(?=^.{4,253}$)` is easy, I can just verify the length of the string, but for the negative lookahead `(?!-)` I'm having some trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `((?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.)+` means 1 or more repetitions of:

- `(?!-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,62}` - 0 to 62 letters, digits or `-` with the first char of the sequence not equal to `-`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - a letter or digit
- `\.` - a dot.

Rephrasing: there can be 1 to 63 letters, digits or `-` with no `-` as first or last char of the sequence before `.`.

Use `([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+` instead, it will match 1 or more repetitions of:

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` - a letter or digit
- `([a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?` - an optional sequence of 0 to 61 letters, digits or `-` and then 1 obligatory letter or digit should follow
- `\.` - a dot.

So, it matches again 1 to 63 chars with no `-` at the start or end of the digit-letter-hyphen sequence.